# Developer Story title change doesn't work - or does it - no wait it doesn't...WTF

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I'm having a strange issue with the developer story. My title at work recently changed so I went to change it.

When I click save, no errors come up and nothing tells me something is wrong...yet the changes don't go through. Even though the developer story is smart enough to suggest the change (and you'll see it pop up for me suggesting me to put it in), and I select the change and click save but nothing.

It's best to show a video: http://www.screencast.com/t/UZTNEhTd

### Edit

This field in your user edit profile allows the entire string:
`Supervisor Application Development & Engineering Documentation`, and it tacks on this other field with `thyssenkrupp System Engineering, Inc.` shown here:

[image]

Stack Overflow uses both of these fields to select your `Title` on your developer story. I believe the problem is the length of both of these two fields added together is too much to add to the other title field in your actual developer story. The autocomplete shows these two fields combined but the developer story title must have a MAX LENGTH that cannot handle all of this. Clearly there is a bug here.

Needs a notification or open it up to more characters to take both fields correctly.

Comment: But it didnt if I look at my developer story.  It actually now gets rid of the "nc" in Inc: Supervisor Application Development & Engineering Documentation at thyssenkrupp System Engineering, I

Comment: Looks like a bug when selecting the pre-existing entry? But it works when you enter any random string yourself?

Comment: It wont let me enter more characters after a certain amount of characters.  Watch the video how it stops me from writing the entire word "documentation".  But if I paste it in it takes it or selects the auto complete it takes it but saving doesnt really work.  No errors in console though.  There is some confusion I believe in some fields...I'll post the fields.

Comment: Ah, OK, I wasn't following your vid correctly. I see what you mean, now.

Comment: @MikeM. - no problem - I also posted the fields in question.  A user's profile field takes the entire title in one field and the company in another field and then combines them.  The combination of both of these fields cannot fit the title in the developer story (it appears).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this bug! Like you mentioned, when setting the Title field in your Developer Story, we suggest your Current Position from the Career section of your Edit Profile page given that you have provided Work information. We miscalculated the max length property on the title field to be 100 characters, when it should've been 225. This will be fixed shortly with our next production build.

Comment: ok but dont forget to handle > 225 length.  This doesn't get rid of the bug.